# Ways to record static data that changes in certain time period

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL database server with Netty server.

Let me briefly describe what I am trying to do,

1. sort user table by some algorithm --> static data
2. users request specific rows from that sorted table according to some factors. --> dynamic data

#1 part of my server is done once a day, #2 is done frequently.

I thought of several ways to store/retrieve static data, such as, actually creating a new table and store sorted data, or simply store it in-memory, or just do #1 every request... However, they seem pretty inefficient to me.

(Having two tables that has the same data seems bad idea to me... In-memory sounds just scary because I could lose the data... third option is just something stupid IMO)

What is a normal practice when you have to store static data that changes daily?

Comment: Add a column to your user table and call it `ordinal` (since `order` is reserved). Have it be a single integer that is updated once a day to the right order for that row (i.e. first row = 1, second row = 2, etc.). Now, you can order on that column at any time.

Comment: Hamza that sounds like a good answer, you should post it as one.